# How to mount nfsv4 folder directly instead of root

Tags: nfsv4

Running CentOS 8

```
server side: /etc/exports:
/home/share *(ro)
```

/home and /home/share is owned by root.root and has 755 permissions on directories, 644 permission on files.

```
 client side:
 mount -t nfs4 server:/ /sharefolder
```

How do I directly mount /home/share to /sharefolder instead of mounting the root of the fs?  If I try "mount -t nfs4 server:/home/share /sharefolder", I get an "Operation not permitted" error

Comment: You wrote /folder/share in your /etc/exports file and you say you're trying to mount /home/share, and then your mount command again says /folder/share... Is it a typo? What folder are you sharing?

Comment: can you see the folder you're sharing ? what does showmount -e output ?

Comment: I get this output from showmount "clnt_create: RPC: Unable to receive" even with selinux and firewall disabled.  I can't see the folder, I get "Operation not permitted"

Answer (score 1):

`mount -t nfs4 server:/home/share /sharefolder` looks like a correct command client-side, and your set-up works for me as I just tested it.

Of course, you must enter the command as root, or use `sudo` with it. The "Operation not permitted" error message suggests perhaps you accidentally ran the command as a non-root user, or mistyped the share name.

Note that even if you export and mount just `server:/home/share`, the NFSv4 server will need to auto-generate *virtual exports* for `/` and `/home`. However, these will not be the NFS server's real `/` nor `/home`, but virtual read-only directories that only contain the minimum necessary sub-directories to reach the actually-exported directories. Once the share has been mounted, you can see this at `/proc/fs/nfsd/exports` on the NFS server:

```
cat /proc/fs/nfsd/exports
# Version 1.1
# Path Client(Flags) # IPs
/home   *(ro,insecure,no_root_squash,sync,no_wdelay,no_subtree_check,v4root,uuid=e4c0fcd4:00b94db3:b63bd9a8:0e705e29,sec=390003:390004:390005:1)
/home/share     *(ro,root_squash,sync,wdelay,no_subtree_check,uuid=e4c0fcd4:00b94db3:b63bd9a8:0e705e29,sec=1)
/       *(ro,insecure,no_root_squash,sync,no_wdelay,no_subtree_check,v4root,fsid=0,uuid=e4c0fcd4:00b94db3:b63bd9a8:0e705e29,sec=390003:390004:390005:1)
```

Comment: yes, I see the same output in /proc/fs/nfsd/exports.   However, I cannot mount server:/home/share, only server:/        However, ls /sharefolder/home/share, gives me "Operation not permitted"

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of testing I managed to reproduce your problem, and it turns out to be firewall issue. Please make sure firewall is disabled and verify that your `nfs` share works afterwards.

Assuming that you use `firewalld`:

```
sudo systemctl stop firewalld
```

Once you determine that `nfs` works as expected you'll want to change your firewall configuration.
`nfs` relies on other daemon processes so in order for `nfs` to work correctly, you need to let through not only `nfs`, but also `mountd` and `rpc-bind`

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=rpc-bind
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=mountd
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=nfs
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

You can also specify a zone if you want these services allowed only for specific zone by adding i.e. `--zone=nfszone`

I haven't thoroughly tested this solution and you might need to open additional port in order to have all the functionalities working (i.e. file locking) See https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/storage_administration_guide/s2-nfs-nfs-firewall-config

Comment: I tried turn turning off the firewall and selinux on both sides and still get the error. Note that I'm using nfsv4

Comment: what do you mean 'tried' ? what firewall are you using? can you confirm that it is stopped?

Comment: When I encountered the issue, the first thing I did was turn off the firewall and disable selinux, then remount.  I ran into the same error.  I verified the firewall was turned off with systemctl status firewalld.  I am using firewalld.  Note that I am using nfsv4 so rpc-bind is not actually required.  The mount "succeeds" even with the firewall on (because I already configured it to allow nfs).  The error is when I try to access the folder.